# What is the Best way to convert List<Byte> to List<Integer>

Tags: java, generics

Which is the best method to convert Currently I am using something like below

```
List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
List<Object> integers = Arrays.asList(bytes.toArray());
```

Then each object inside integers needs to be typecast to Integer. Is there any other way in which I can achieve this?

Comment: You can't typecast a `Byte` to an `Integer` so what your code probably does is the sequence unbox--convert-box. Any other ways to do this will still involve explicit loops or 3rd party libs.

Comment: Youcould manually loop over the byte list, cast the objects and add them to the int list

Comment: `asList` will only create a copy of the list, without changing the contents of the list.

Comment: @SJuan76 `asList` by itself doesn't copy anything. It just exposes the contents of the array as a `List`. `toArray()` is the one doing the copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the standard JDK, here's how to do it

```
List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
// [...] Fill the bytes list somehow

List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Byte b : bytes) {
  integers.add(b == null ? null : b.intValue());
}
```

If you're sure, you don't have any `null` values in `bytes`:

```
for (byte b : bytes) {
  integers.add((int) b);
}
```

Comment: `for (byte b : bytes) integers.add((int)b)` will also work and looks like what OP is doing currently.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: You're right, yet that is assuming that `nulls` aren't allowed

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik could that not throw NPE?

Comment: @assylias and Lukas, you are both right. I am just commenting on what OP seems to be doing right now and apparently it's working for him.

Answer (score 0):

If Google's Guava available in your project:

```
// assume listofBytes is of type List<Byte>
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = Ints.asList(Ints.toArray(listOfBytes));
```